# ASP.NET issue can't load 'msvcm80.dll' DLL

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I work on multiple web projects. There is one I haven't touched in months and now when I'm trying to build and debug it I get an error "Could not load file or assembly 'msvcm80.DLL'".

It never hits any portion of the code and begins debugging from what I can tell. I don't know of any msvcm80.DLL , so I assume it is a reference for ASP.NET. Any idea what on earth this is and how to fix it?

I'm running this as on a Local IIS page.

Edit:
Project builds fine, no errors. It just throws the error in deployment. I'm unsure what this is as I've never seen this dll though reading implies its something for visual studio 2005 which I have no idea why that's a dependency on any of my items.

Edit2:

```
Full Error Message
Server Error in '/VaultWebApi' Application.
Could not load file or assembly 'msvcm80.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'msvcm80.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'msvcm80.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +36
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +152
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +77
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +21
   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +28
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +38

[ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly 'msvcm80.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.]
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +726
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() +196
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai) +45
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +172
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies() +91
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +111
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +156
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +695

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'msvcm80.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +659
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +89
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +189
```

Comment: It doesn't even build? Can you post the entire build or runtime error?

Comment: Have you tried removing the reference entirely?

Comment: @Zenacity  It doesn't show as a reference in my project which is what confuses me.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning There are no build errors. The missing DLL is the only runtime error I'm seeing.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Full error message added, this is the only error message I get. None of the code I've written seems to get hit. Logging doesn't give any more information.